# Join type based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables:

```
shops
id | shop_name | shop_type

products
id | shop_id | product_name
```

I need to `LEFT JOIN products ON products.shop_id = shops.id IF shop_type is 0`
and I need to `JOIN products ON products.shop_id = shops.id IF shop_type is 1`.
What's the fastest solution? It does not matter if code will be very dirty, performance is the most important thing there..

Comment: @hnn, a case expression can't be used like that...

Comment: That is a very strange requirement.  You should perhaps explain what your data is and what results you want.

Comment: @jarlh answered my question, I can't believe the answer was so obvious. It seems that last hours of Friday are the hardest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from shops LEFT JOIN products ON products.shop_id = shops.id
where shop_type = 0 or (products.shop_id is not NULL and shop_type = 1)
```